# override default ALT action in WPF

Tags: wpf, menu, alt

I'm working on a WPF application and I want to show/hide the menu when the users press ALT. The following piece of code works when I press the right alt key but not with the left one. When the menu is visible, clicking on right AlT key selects the first entry of my menu (which is well a main menu) instead of hiding it.

So I suppose that right ALT key has a default behaviour I have to override inside my event or somewhere else.

```
   private void Window_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.LeftAlt || e.Key == Key.RightAlt)
        {
            this.Show_HideMenu(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried PreviewKeyDown event?

Comment: Yes, I've already tried.